# Library in Apple TV music app is empty

Tags: music, appletv

As my latest generation AppleTv upgraded it's os to the latest my library in the music app emptied. Previously it showed all my playlists and it synced with my devices.
[image]
However my playlists are downloaded from the server when I try to add the to a playlist so this means the iCloud sync is working

[image]

Comment: Are you running the latest version of iOS on your devices / macOS on your Mac (if applicable)?

Comment: I was showing you pure appletv screens so I assume the screens were generated by appletvOs

Comment: Where is the music supposed to be coming from? My first comment assumed you were trying to use Home Sharing but I realize now your question doesn't actually state what music you're trying to access.

Comment: I am accessing my music app which plays a Apple Music subscription.

Comment: Try logging out with your Apple ID and waiting 15 minutes and then logging back in.

Comment: Oh right... I will try thx. The good old turn it off an on again paradigm :))